# Twitter Bootstrap Validator: Only display red error css

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using Bootstrap Validator with my forms and would like to only show the visual cues when a input box is invalid not when values are valid (green). Is there a way to customize the validator css. I tried removing the valid code from the css/js file but it negates any css coloring.

See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean.

Maybe you can override these css code below or delete them in bootstrap.css

```
.has-success .form-control{ border-color:inherit !important;}
.has-success .form-control:focus { border-color:inherit !important;}
```

[image: pic about the class]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the code you suggested but it didn't change anything when I validated the form (clicking save). To further explain my question, I would like to know how to remove the css-green coloring from the validations. So that when the input boxes pass validations it doesn't change the lettering and input border to green.

Comment: When the green color showing you can right click on it -> inspect the element and see which `.class` cause it.